# Dismiss DialogFragment(not Dialog) onTouchOutside

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments, touch-event, android-dialogfragment

I have searched through all the answers about dismissing a Dialog **onTouchOutside**, however, I am using **DialogFragment** in my application. How can I achieve dismissing the **DialogFragment** when user clicks outside the **DialogFragment's** region.

I have examined **Dialog**'s [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/app/Dialog.java#Dialog.isOutOfBounds%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) for **setCanceledOnTouchOutside**

```
public void setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel) {
    if (cancel && !mCancelable) {
        mCancelable = true;
    }

    mCanceledOnTouchOutside = cancel;
}
```

There's another function which may be interesting which is **isOutOfBounds**

```
private boolean isOutOfBounds(MotionEvent event) {
    final int x = (int) event.getX();
    final int y = (int) event.getY();
    final int slop = ViewConfiguration.get(mContext).getScaledWindowTouchSlop();
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    return (x < -slop) || (y < -slop)
    || (x > (decorView.getWidth()+slop))
    || (y > (decorView.getHeight()+slop));
}
```

but I couldn't figure out a way to make use of these for **DialogFragment**

In addition to these I have examined the state of the application with [hierarchyviewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html)
and as I understand it, I can only see the region of the dialog and not the outsied part of it (I mean the remaining part of the screen after the **DialogFragment**).

*Can you suggest a way of implementing this **setCanceledOnTouchOutside** for **DialogFragment** and if possible with a sample code?*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment(); // init in onCreate() or somewhere else
...
if ( fragment.getDialog() != null )
    fragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); // after fragment has already dialog, i. e. in onCreateView()
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setShowsDialog%28boolean%29 for more info about dialogs in DialogFragments.

Comment: `DialogFragment` does not have a method called `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()` `Dialog` has. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Above answer does not imply it has. `DialogFragment` has method `getDialog()` which returns `Dialog` which HAS method `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()`. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: Oh man.. please be more descriptive.. If you can edit the answer I can upvote it. I have called it inside `onCreateView()` of a custom `DialogFragment` implementation and it works well. Thanks.

Comment: I found that I need to add the call to seCanceledOnTouchOutside(true) on Honeycomb but not on ICS.

Comment: I would think a better answer would be to have the dialog fragment subclass control whether it should be cancelable. Good places to do so seem to be in onCreateDialog or onCreateView.

Answer (score 11):

In most cases, getDialog() is null, since you won't get it immediately after you make a new instance of your dialog.

As suggested above `onViewCreated` is also nor correct for `DialogFragment` especially when using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`.

The below works well, as it's placed on the `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getDialog() != null) {
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Override this method in your DialogFragment. That wasn't clear initially as it is commonly overridden in Fragments.

Comment: @ericosg I am using androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment and the above answer does not work in my DialogFragment.  My test device uses Android 8.0 Oreo and my use case is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825258/android-how-to-dismiss-a-datepicker-dialogfragment-when-touching-outside.  Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just override `onCreateDialog` and just set it there. That way you don't have to check for null on the `getDialog()` call all the time.

```
 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Dialog d =  super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
     d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
     return d;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was reading: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

It states: "Control of the dialog (deciding when to show, hide, dismiss it) should be done through the API here, not with direct calls on the dialog."

Answer (score 0):

I have answered to another question, but that answer is more appropriate for this problem, [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043015/2049781) . Just to brief here, I simply implemented `onTouch()` of `DialogFragment`'s `getView()` and checked touch bounds.