# Find out when Dialog has been closed by clicking anywhere in the activity

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-dialog

I need to run some code where my alert dialog gets closed other then by just dismissing it via clicking on the buttons. The user can close a dialog by clicking somewhere on the activity in the background.

I've managed to get this to work like here:

```
    private void InfoAlert()
    {
        alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.SetTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.HiThere));
        alert.SetMessage(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.BetaGame));

        alert.SetNeutralButton(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.GotIt), (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_Login));
            StartActivity(activity2);
            Finish();
        });


        alert.SetOnCancelListener(new ProgressDialogCancel(this, this));
        Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.Show();

    }

public class ProgressDialogCancel : Java.Lang.Object, IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListener
{
    private Context _context;
    private readonly Activity _activity;

    public ProgressDialogCancel(Context context, Activity activity)
    {
        _context = context;
        _activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
    {
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.btnInsta.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.btnFB.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.btnCreateAccount.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.btnExplain.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.btnLogin.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.ln1.SetBackgroundResource(0);
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.ln1.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"));
        Activity_AcctCreationLogin.alert.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But since I would need to run so much code from the other class, this is a very unclean solution. Idealy, there would be a way of doing it like this:

```
alert.SetOnCancelListener += delegate
{
//do something
};
```

How would I achieve something like this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you need to handle [DismissEvent](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Android.Widget.ListPopupWindow.DismissEvent/) like this:

```
var dialog = new Dialog(CONTEXT);
// SetContentView, SetTitle, ...

dialog.DismissEvent += (s, e) =>
{
    // do whatever you need here, this will be called on
    // dismiss (clicking on cancel button or outside of dialog)
};
```

Comment: works great! only thing is ive noticed this way to be a lot slower than my method. but it is a perfect solution. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about performance, but I think this is the correct and also clean way, (dialog has dismiss event, so we should use that, I think), of course I didn't try your solution. btw dialog is not that heavy to worry about performance. anyway glad to help, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

one solution might be-  but do  remember `.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` has to be called in onCreate method

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

or override `onTouchEvent()`  and check for action type. if the action type is 'MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE' means, user is interacting outside the dialog region. So in this case, you can dimiss your dialog

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
        System.out.println("dismiss dialog");  
               this.dismiss();  
       }  
       return false;  
}
```

for other possible solutions refer:
  [How to dismiss a DialogFragment when pressing outside the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404140/how-to-dismiss-a-dialogfragment-when-pressing-outside-the-dialog)

OR 
[Allow outside touch for DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382540/allow-outside-touch-for-dialogfragment/28043015#28043015)

Comment: interestting. but i found out that instantiating a new object of my first class and then having the lines of code inside my first class is easier. tho it intantiates a new dialog multiple times...