# Allow outside touch for DialogFragment: Android 9

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, touch

I am aware of

[Allow outside touch for DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382540/allow-outside-touch-for-dialogfragment/28043015)

and its accepted answer. I've tested the accepted answer on the following:

```
Galaxy Tab A 9.7 Android 7.1.1: ok
Galaxy Tab A 8.0 Android 7    : ok
Galaxy Tab S4 Android 9       : no touch outside DialogFragment
Galaxy S5 Android 6.0.1       : ok
Galaxy Tab S2 Android 7       : ok
Galaxy Tab S3 Android 9       : no touch outside DialogFragment
Galaxy Tab S4 Android 9       : no touch outside DialogFragment
Galaxy Note Edge Android 6.0.1: ok
Galaxy Note4 Android 6.0.1    : ok
```

and several other, non-Samsung phones running Android 6, 7 and 7.1.1 - all ok.

It really looks like the accepted answer does not work on Android 9. Precisely what happens is that when I try pressing a button which is outside the DialogFragment, it's onClick() method does not get called.

Any pointers?

Comment: Now I have also tested on two phones running Android 10 - both of them behave just like Android 9. So bottom line: everything <9 works, 9 and 10 do not.

Comment: Very strange. When i try the very same app on an emulator running API level 28, 29 or R, things work just fine.

Comment: Even better - now I've tested on a Huawei Mate Pro running Android 9, and over there it's working. So it is looking like this is not working only on Samsung phones running Android 9 or 10.