# Android: how to dismiss a DatePicker DialogFragment when touching outside?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I have a working DatePickerFragment that extends DialogFragment.  I set up a DatePickerDialog in onCreateDialog() and then tried to add:

"picker.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);"

I am testing on a device with Android 8.0 Oreo and nothing happens when touching outside the DatePicker dialog.  I am using androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity as my BaseActivity and androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment for the DialogFragment;

Code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
    **picker.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);**
    return picker;
```

This is the Activity code that creates the Fragment:

```
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
// tried the below also, with no luck
**newFragment.setCancelable(true);**
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

I also tried the below in the DialogFragment, also with no luck:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
   ... 
   }
```

and:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getDialog() != null) {
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

I referenced this post for possible answers:  [How to dismiss a DialogFragment when pressing outside the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404140/how-to-dismiss-a-dialogfragment-when-pressing-outside-the-dialog). What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi, can you post the source code to show the date picker dialog?

Comment: I did, its created in onCreateDialog() and is shown above.  Was there something else you were looking for?

Comment: Hi @AJW, I meant the statement where you call the DialogFragment. Sth. like `myDatePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmenetManager(), "tag")`

Comment: Ah, ok I will add now, above.

Comment: add a parent layout which expands on the whole screen. add a click listener on parent and when parent is clicked then dismiss the dialog

Comment: I think I had placed `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside()` in `onStart` of my fragment and it worked for me.
If this doesn't work I would suggest debugging using `isCancelable` across your `DatePickerFragment`.
Also, are you using a custom layout for the Dialog?

Comment: @Saurabh I was not using a custom layout but will be trying that next.  Do you know if getDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside() would be better in onViewCreated() rather than onStart()?

Comment: @AJW I doubt that would make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to dismiss Dialog that extends DialogFragment, write

> setCancelable(true);

inside onCreateView. The dialog will dismiss when you touching outside.

example code :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     setCancelable(true);
     return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: See above: "I also tried the below in the DialogFragment, also with no luck:  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
   ... 
   } "

Comment: without getdalog(). its only 1 row code. i edit my answer with example use

Comment: I am using a DatePicker inside the dialog.  How do I get the id for the "R.layout.dialog_cari_barang" so I know what to inflate as the view?  There is no xml with an id for the DatePicker.

Comment: Sorry, i give you my own code. now i edit my answer with your explained code above.

Comment: Answer upvoted and accepted and bounty awarded.  The key was using onCreateView() and the inflater.  What does "return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);" do in your code answer?

Comment: I guess fragment will return default view if you return super.onCreateView. But I usually create fragment or dialog fragment with choose/check create layout xml. So i can edit my layout (custom view). And return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false) like my old answer.

Comment: And why u not directly using DatePickerDialog instead using dialog fragment?

Answer (score 1):

did you try to set the dialog to cancelable

```
picker.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: I did not, I will try it.  Do I have to set that in addition to the "setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);" or just setCancelable() on its own?

Comment: No luck.  I tried setCancelable() on its own and also tried it and added "setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);" but neither worked.

Comment: try to use dialogFragmnet.setCancelable(true);

Comment: do you mean add that in the Activity where the code creates the dialogfragment?

Comment: No luck adding "newFragment.setCancelable(true)" in the Activity, after the DatePickerFragment is created, before "newFragment.show...);"

Comment: can you show me the Dialog fragment class you created

Answer (score 0):

I thought I have similar problem, but it seems in my case that dialog has some shadow padding around it and I had to click outside of it very close to the edge of the screen to cancel it.

This is how i create my dialog:

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

val dpd = context?.let {
    DatePickerDialog(it, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, pickedYear, pickedMonth, pickedDay ->

         //do something with picked date.

    }, year, month, day)
}

dpd?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
dpd?.show()
```

Try to set `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` in your implementation and try to dismiss it on tap very close to the edge of the screen, maybe test it on some big screen emulator like Pixel 3 XL. Now i know that this is not a solution and you need to handle all kind of devices and screen sizes, but I want you to verify that you might have same problem as me: that dialog **will** be canceled on touch outside, but this "outside" is not so obvious and it might be a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add setCancelable(true) in your Dialog onCreate method or in constructor

Comment: Isn't it the same duplicated answer like @Fahad Alotaibi ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the default DatePickerDialog from android which is default close when selecting out side the dialog.

[Try this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog) is still issue let me know will send the proper code for same